# Desktop PC with two 5.25" drive bays

Tags: desktop, case

My parents need a new desktop PC, so I was just going to get them one from Dell or HP or some other company that sells prebuilt PCs.

My parents' current desktop PC has two 5.25" optical drives in it, and I was planning on taking those out and putting them into the new PC.

But looking around, I can't find any prebuilt PCs with 5.25" drive bays.  I've only found prebuilt desktops with at most one thin slot on the case and a slim notebook style optical drive inside.

Does anyone sell a prebuilt desktop PC with two 5.25" drive bays, Windows 10, and a SSD hard drive for around $800 or less?

Comment: @BennettYeo He's asking about drive bays, and asking about optical drives in particular, not hard drives.

Answer (score 2):

Acer has some [Veriton M](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/IN/content/professional-models/desktops/veritonm) desktops that have two 5 1/4" drive bays.  For example the [M4660G](https://www.provantage.com/acer-ud-p02aa-03s~7ACED13V.htm) model and [M6650G](https://www.cdw.com/product/acer-veriton-m6650g-i5750s-mt-core-i5-7500-3.4-ghz-8-gb-256-gb/5469332) model are both available with a 256 GB SSD drive for under $800.

I also found the [Lenovo P520c](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/think-workstations/thinkstation-p-series-towers/ThinkStation-P520c/p/33TS3TP520C) desktop that has two 5 1/4" bays, although that is over $800.